# The following works in development on a local host but in production does not

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, timer

I created a class that has a timer that calls a function created in my Azure account to return the status of azure, the return value is cached. In the class I have an WEB API that returns the cached value.

I have Windows form software that calls the WEB API once a minute to get the status.

This all works fine in development on a local host but not in production.

```
[EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")]
public class AzureStatusController : ApiController
{
    private readonly int statusTimerInterval = 60 * 1000; // every 60 seconds

    private static bool cloudStatus = false;

    static HttpClient client;
    private static string url = "";
    private static string code = "";

    private System.Threading.Timer cloudTimer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Classes Ctor
    /// </summary>
    public AzureStatusController()
    {
        cloudTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnAzureStatusCallback, null, 0, statusTimerInterval);

        url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudFunctionsBaseUrl"].ToString();
        code = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudStatusCode"].ToString();
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    private void OnAzureStatusCallback(object state)
    {
        var status = false;
        if (client != null && client.BaseAddress.ToString().Length > 30 && code.Length > 70)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(code);
                if (response != null && !response.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var result = response.Result;
                    if (result != null && result.IsSuccessStatusCode && result.Content != null)
                    {
                        string responseString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim().ToLower();
                        status = (responseString.Contains("ok"));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                status = false;
            }
        }
        cloudStatus = status;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the cached value of the Azure status
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/AzureStatus")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(cloudStatus);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I may be missing?

Comment: If I understand correctly you have three elements: 1) An Azure Function generating a status message 2) A WebAPI controller that polls the function every minute and stores the cached value which is then available to 3) A Windows Forms app.

The question I have is this- which of those 3 pieces is not working in production and what specifically isn't working? For example the message getting lost, an error is being thrown, or the timer isn't firing. If you are getting an error please edit to add the stack trace.

Posting the relevant code for forms and functions may also help.

Comment: I was getting a blanket error message {"Message":"An error has occurred."}. There was no stack to trace. I did end up having my sysadmin turn on server debugging and I received a little more info (not really useful though). After more testing I found the issue to be the .ToString() part of the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings calls. This also made little sense though getting rid of the .ToString() did fix my problem.

Comment: It is working now?

Comment: Yes. I apologize for not making that clear in my reply.

Comment: Awesome! Please consider posting this as an answer- it will make it easier for other people who are in the same situation to find the solution.

Comment: I have done this, thank you for the suggestion and your time!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding that adding .ToString() to the end of my ConfigurationManager.AppSettings call was causing problem in production but not in development. Rather than spend any more time on this problem I ended up going with the following code:

```
public class AzureStatusController : ApiController
{
    private static bool cloudStatus = false;
    private static DateTime expiration;

    /// <summary>
    /// Classes Ctor
    /// </summary>
    public AzureStatusController()
    {
        expiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    }

    private void CheckAzureStatus()
    {
        var status = false;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // the following 2 lines should be changed to retrieve the info from 
            var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudFunctionsBaseUrl"];
            var code = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudStatusCode"];
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            try
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(code);
                if (response != null && !response.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var result = response.Result;
                    if (result != null && result.IsSuccessStatusCode && result.Content != null)
                    {
                        string responseString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Trim().ToLower();
                        status = (responseString.Contains("ok"));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                status = false;
            }
        }
        cloudStatus = status;
        expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the cached value of the Azure status
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/AzureStatus")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        if (expiration < DateTime.Now)
        {
            CheckAzureStatus();
        }
        return Ok(cloudStatus);
    }
}
```